# Convergence of a series using Taylor expansion, parameter of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I have a series:

$$\ \sum_{n=1}| \tan (\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}))-\frac{1}{\sqrt n}|^a~~ a>0$$

To estimate the convergence depending on a, ~using Taylor series.
I have calculated the difference in the module using Taylor series:

$$\ \frac{1}{36n^4}(1-\frac{1}{18\sqrt n}) + \frac{1}{6n\sqrt n}(1-\frac{1}{n}) $$

What can I do else? How can I solve it? Is it wrong? How can I determine the convergence?

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$
\tan \left( {\sin \left( {\sqrt x } \right)} \right) - \sqrt x  = \frac{{x^{3/2} }}
{6} + o\left( {x^{3/2} } \right)
$$
you have that
$$
a_n=\left( {\sin \left( {\sqrt {\frac{1}
{n}} } \right)} \right) - \sqrt {\frac{1}
{n}}  = \frac{1}
{{6n^{3/2} }} + o\left( {\frac{1}
{{n^{3/2} }}} \right)
$$
Thus you have to consider the series 
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}
{{n^{\left( {3/2} \right)a} }}} 
$$
This is convergent as log as $3a/2 >1$ while is divergent if  $3a/2 \leq 1$. Thus your series is convergent as long as $a> 2/3$. your calculation are the same of mine but it missing the error term.

Comment: So, in Taylor series, I take the first element of the series- $\ x^{3/2}/6 $ - regardless the powers of the rest?

Comment: Since x=1/n the other terms are much smaller than this one and so they are 
negligible. When you use a Taylor's development you always must consider the error term because you must be sure that it is smaller than the main term